# Let $E$ and $F$ Banach spaces and $T\in L(E,F)$. If $\dim( R(T))<\infty$ then $\dim( R(T'))<\infty$.

Tags: linear-algebra, functional-analysis, banach-spaces

I need to show the following:

> Let $E$ and $F$ Banach spaces and $T\in L(E,F)$  with $\dim( R(T))<\infty$ where $R(T)$ is the image of $T$.  Show that  $\dim( R(T'))<\infty$  where $R(T')$ is the image of $T'$ and $T'$ is the adjoint operator of $T$, furthermore, show that $\dim( R(T))=\dim( R(T'))$.

**Remark:** If $E$ and $F$ were Hilbert spaces then $(\ker(T))^{\bot}\cong R(T)$, in general, as $\dim(R(T))<\infty$ then $\overline{R(T)}=R(T)$, this implies that $R(T')=\ker(T)^{\bot}$. Therefore,  $R(T')\cong R(T)$, then $\dim( R(T'))=\dim( R(T))<\infty$.

The **problem** is that I do not know if in Banach spaces it is true to say that $(\ker(T))^{\bot}\cong R(T)$. If this is not true, I would like to know a proof without using that fact.

Comment: When you don't have an inner product, consider $V/W$ instead of $W^\perp$ in $V$.

Comment: If $X^{\perp}$ denotes the annihilator of $X\subset E$, then $(\ker T)^{\perp}$ is generally the weak$^{\ast}$ closure of $R(T')$. Here, the closed range theorem tells us that $R(T')$ is weak$^{\ast}$-closed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $A \overset{f}\longrightarrow B \overset{g}\longrightarrow C$, where $A, B, C$ are Banach spaces and $f, g$ are bounded linear maps, then
$A^* \overset{f'}\longleftarrow B^* \overset{g'}\longleftarrow C^*$, and $(g\circ f)' = f'\circ g'$.    Let $T_1: E \to R(T)$ and let $\iota : R(T) \to F$ be the inclusion. (Note that $R(T)$ is closed.)   Then $T = \iota\circ T_1$.  Hence $T' = T_1' \circ \iota'$ factors through the finite dimensional space $R(T)^*$, so has finite dimensional range.

Remark:  $\iota'$ is just *restriction* of a continuous linear functional on $F$ to $R(T)$.  Moreover, $R(T') = \ker(T)^o$, the set of continuous linear functionals on $E$ which restrict to zero on $\ker(T)$.